# Output of proc.communicate() does not format newlines in django python

Tags: python, django, django-views, popen

I have a subprocess using communicate to get the output ans saving it to my database:

```
  p = Popen([str(pre_sync), '-avu', str(src), str(dest)], stdout=PIPE)
  syncoutput = p.communicate()
  check.log = syncoutput
```

It all works fine, but the output from communicate looks like this:

```
('sending incremental file list\n\nsent 89 bytes  received 13 bytes  204.00 bytes/sec\ntotal size is 25  speedup is 0.25\n', None)
```

All in a single line and with the "\n" inserted. Is there a way I can make it print each line in a new line? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
syncoutput,sync_error = p.communicate()
print(syncoutput)
```

[p.communicate()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns a 2-tuple, composed of the output from stdout and stderr. When you print the 2-tuple, you see the `\n` characters. When you print the string (of the new `syncoutput`), you will get formatted text.

Comment: @dura, be sure to **accept** this answer (check on the checkmark-shaped icon to the A's left) -- "thanks are cheap, but accepts matter" is part of SO's basic etiquette!-)